# Better Latency with PortAudio and ASIO driver

Tags: c++, portaudio, asio

I'm working on simple drum trigger input detector that plays a drum sample when it detects trigger input. I'm having trouble with high latency.

```
const PaDeviceInfo* deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(defaultInputDevice);
std::cout << "Default Input Device Host API: " << Pa_GetHostApiInfo(deviceInfo->hostApi)->name << std::endl;
```

this shows that this program is using MME driver for input.
My question is how to switch to ASIO (or any other driver that reduces latency)

here is the whole code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <portaudio.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    
    const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    const int FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 256;
    
    int audioCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer,
        unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
        const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
        PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
        void* userData);
    
    int main() {
        PaError err;
        err = Pa_Initialize();
        if (err != paNoError) {
            std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    
        PaDeviceIndex defaultInputDevice = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
        if (defaultInputDevice == paNoDevice) {
            std::cerr << "No default input device found!" << std::endl;
            Pa_Terminate();
            return 1;
        }
    
        // Set up input parameters
        PaStreamParameters inputParameters;
        inputParameters.device = defaultInputDevice;
        inputParameters.channelCount = 1;
        inputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; 
        inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(defaultInputDevice)->defaultLowInputLatency;
        inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = nullptr;
    
        PaStream* stream;
        err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream,
            &inputParameters,
            nullptr,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
            paClipOff,
            audioCallback,
            nullptr);
    
        if (err != paNoError) {
            std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
            Pa_Terminate();
            return 1;
        }
    
        err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
        if (err != paNoError) {
            std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
            Pa_CloseStream(stream);
            Pa_Terminate();
            return 1;
        }
    
    
        std::cout << "Microphone level (normalized):" << std::endl;
    
        while (true) {
            Pa_Sleep(1000);
        }
    
        // Cleanup
        err = Pa_StopStream(stream);
        if (err != paNoError) {
            std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        }
    
        err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
        if (err != paNoError) {
            std::cerr << "PortAudio error: " << Pa_GetErrorText(err) << std::endl;
        }
    
        Pa_Terminate();
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Audio callback function
    int audioCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer,
        unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
        const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
        PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
        void* userData) {
    
        const float* input = static_cast<const float*>(inputBuffer);
    
        // RMS
        float trigLevel = 0.0f;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; ++i) {
            trigLevel += input[i] * input[i];
        }
        trigLevel = std::sqrt(trigLevel / framesPerBuffer) * float(std::pow(10.0, 5));
    
        static bool legalHit = true;
        if (trigLevel > 900.0f && legalHit) {
            std::cout << "Trigger Input Level (RMS): " << trigLevel << std::endl;
    
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\11.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
    
            Sleep(50);
    
            legalHit = false;
        }
        else if (trigLevel < 900.0f)
        {
            legalHit = true;
        }
    
        return paContinue;
    }
```

If there is a way to reduce latency without using any other audio driver please let me know.

Comment: You have a "Sleep" in your audio thread.  Removing that will drop your latency.

Comment: @UKMonkey But its after the sound is Played. I tested it and without it the latency is same and I get multiple triggering from by bass drum. I think there has to be some delay before the next sound is played to prevent double triggering.